# How to make HTML tree list using knockout

Tags: html, knockout.js, tree, treeview

I am using knockout and I want to make HTML Treelist 
there is the data I have

```
 self.CountriesList = ko.observableArray([{ "CountryID": 2008, "parentId": 0, "fullName": "Asia", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 0, "LocalName": "Asia", "LatinName": "Asia"  }, 
{ "CountryID": 2009, "parentId": 0, "fullName": "Africa", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 0, "LocalName": "Africa", "LatinName": "Africa"  }, 
{ "CountryID": 2010, "parentId": 0, "fullName": "Europe", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 0, "LocalName": "Europe", "LatinName": "Europe"  }, 
{ "CountryID": 2011, "parentId": 0, "fullName": "Australia", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 0, "LocalName": "Australia", "LatinName": "Australia"  }, 
{ "CountryID": 2012, "parentId": 0, "fullName": "North America", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 0, "LocalName": "North America", "LatinName": "North America"  }, { "CountryID": 2013, "parentId": 0, "fullName": "South America", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 0, "LocalName": "South America", "LatinName": "South America"  }, { "CountryID": 2014, "parentId": 2009, "fullName": "Algeria", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2009, "LocalName": "Algeria", "LatinName": "Algeria"  }, { "CountryID": 2015, "parentId": 2009, "fullName": "Angola", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2009, "LocalName": "Angola", "LatinName": "Angola"  }, { "CountryID": 2016, "parentId": 2011, "fullName": "Australia", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2011, "LocalName": "Australia", "LatinName": "Australia"  }, { "CountryID": 2017, "parentId": 2009, "fullName": "Cameroon", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2009, "LocalName": "Cameroon", "LatinName": "Cameroon"  }, { "CountryID": 2018, "parentId": 2009, "fullName": "Egypt", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2009, "LocalName": "ُEgypt", "LatinName": "Egypt"  }, { "CountryID": 2019, "parentId": 2010, "fullName": "France", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2010, "LocalName": "France", "LatinName": "France"  }, { "CountryID": 2020, "parentId": 2010, "fullName": "Italy", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2010, "LocalName": "Italy", "LatinName": "Italy"  }, { "CountryID": 2021, "parentId": 2010, "fullName": "Portugal", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2010, "LocalName": "Portugal", "LatinName": "Portugal"  }, { "CountryID": 2022, "parentId": 2010, "fullName": "England", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2010, "LocalName": "England", "LatinName": "England"  }, { "CountryID": 2023, "parentId": 2010, "fullName": "Spain", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2010, "LocalName": "Spain", "LatinName": "Spain"  }, { "CountryID": 2024, "parentId": 2013, "fullName": "Argentina", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2013, "LocalName": "Argentina", "LatinName": "Argentina"  }, { "CountryID": 2025, "parentId": 2013, "fullName": "Brazil", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2013, "LocalName": "Brazil", "LatinName": "Brazil"  }, { "CountryID": 2026, "parentId": 2013, "fullName": "Colombia", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2013, "LocalName": "Colombia", "LatinName": "Colombia"  }, { "CountryID": 2027, "parentId": 2012, "fullName": "USA", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2012, "LocalName": "USA", "LatinName": "USA"  }, { "CountryID": 2028, "parentId": 2012, "fullName": "Canada", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2012, "LocalName": "Canada", "LatinName": "Canada"  }, { "CountryID": 2029, "parentId": 2012, "fullName": "Mexico", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2012, "LocalName": "Mexico ", "LatinName": "Mexico"  }, { "CountryID": 2030, "parentId": 2008, "fullName": "Malaysia", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2008, "LocalName": "Malaysia ", "LatinName": "Malaysia"  }, { "CountryID": 2031, "parentId": 2008, "fullName": "KSA", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2008, "LocalName": "KSA", "LatinName": "KSA"  }, { "CountryID": 2032, "parentId": 2008, "fullName": "China", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2008, "LocalName": "China", "LatinName": "China"  }, { "CountryID": 2033, "parentId": 2008, "fullName": "India", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2008, "LocalName": "India", "LatinName": "India"  }])
```

here is [CodePen Sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLVPbb) , I want to convert from DxTreelist to HTML

Comment: You need to convert flat array into tree first. Then create a html template for tree node using knockout template and call it recursively in foreach binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help you? I just concat everything in 1 flat result and recursively gathered the children in a template

http://jsfiddle.net/m5o8tsjg/

```js
function TreeNode(id, parentId, name) {
 var self = this;
  self.id = id;
  self.parentId = parentId;
  self.name = name;
  self.isOpen = ko.observable(true);
}

$getCountries = function () {
 var countries = [{ "CountryID": 2008, "parentId": 0, "fullName": "Asia", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 0, "LocalName": "Asia", "LatinName": "Asia"  }, { "CountryID": 2009, "parentId": 0, "fullName": "Africa", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 0, "LocalName": "Africa", "LatinName": "Africa"  }, { "CountryID": 2010, "parentId": 0, "fullName": "Europe", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 0, "LocalName": "Europe", "LatinName": "Europe"  }, { "CountryID": 2011, "parentId": 0, "fullName": "Australia", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 0, "LocalName": "Australia", "LatinName": "Australia"  }, { "CountryID": 2012, "parentId": 0, "fullName": "North America", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 0, "LocalName": "North America", "LatinName": "North America"  }, { "CountryID": 2013, "parentId": 0, "fullName": "South America", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 0, "LocalName": "South America", "LatinName": "South America"  }, { "CountryID": 2014, "parentId": 2009, "fullName": "Algeria", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2009, "LocalName": "Algeria", "LatinName": "Algeria"  }, { "CountryID": 2015, "parentId": 2009, "fullName": "Angola", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2009, "LocalName": "Angola", "LatinName": "Angola"  }, { "CountryID": 2016, "parentId": 2011, "fullName": "Australia", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2011, "LocalName": "Australia", "LatinName": "Australia"  }, { "CountryID": 2017, "parentId": 2009, "fullName": "Cameroon", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2009, "LocalName": "Cameroon", "LatinName": "Cameroon"  }, { "CountryID": 2018, "parentId": 2009, "fullName": "Egypt", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2009, "LocalName": "ُEgypt", "LatinName": "Egypt"  }, { "CountryID": 2019, "parentId": 2010, "fullName": "France", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2010, "LocalName": "France", "LatinName": "France"  }, { "CountryID": 2020, "parentId": 2010, "fullName": "Italy", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2010, "LocalName": "Italy", "LatinName": "Italy"  }, { "CountryID": 2021, "parentId": 2010, "fullName": "Portugal", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2010, "LocalName": "Portugal", "LatinName": "Portugal"  }, { "CountryID": 2022, "parentId": 2010, "fullName": "England", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2010, "LocalName": "England", "LatinName": "England"  }, { "CountryID": 2023, "parentId": 2010, "fullName": "Spain", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2010, "LocalName": "Spain", "LatinName": "Spain"  }, { "CountryID": 2024, "parentId": 2013, "fullName": "Argentina", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2013, "LocalName": "Argentina", "LatinName": "Argentina"  }, { "CountryID": 2025, "parentId": 2013, "fullName": "Brazil", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2013, "LocalName": "Brazil", "LatinName": "Brazil"  }, { "CountryID": 2026, "parentId": 2013, "fullName": "Colombia", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2013, "LocalName": "Colombia", "LatinName": "Colombia"  }, { "CountryID": 2027, "parentId": 2012, "fullName": "USA", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2012, "LocalName": "USA", "LatinName": "USA"  }, { "CountryID": 2028, "parentId": 2012, "fullName": "Canada", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2012, "LocalName": "Canada", "LatinName": "Canada"  }, { "CountryID": 2029, "parentId": 2012, "fullName": "Mexico", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2012, "LocalName": "Mexico ", "LatinName": "Mexico"  }, { "CountryID": 2030, "parentId": 2008, "fullName": "Malaysia", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2008, "LocalName": "Malaysia ", "LatinName": "Malaysia"  }, { "CountryID": 2031, "parentId": 2008, "fullName": "KSA", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2008, "LocalName": "KSA", "LatinName": "KSA"  }, { "CountryID": 2032, "parentId": 2008, "fullName": "China", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2008, "LocalName": "China", "LatinName": "China"  }, { "CountryID": 2033, "parentId": 2008, "fullName": "India", "PARENT": 0, "GROUP_CODE": 2008, "LocalName": "India", "LatinName": "India"  }];
  var mapped = _.map(countries, function (c) { return new TreeNode(c.CountryID, c.parentId, c.fullName);  });
  mapped.unshift(new TreeNode(0, null, 'root'));
  return mapped;
};
$getClubs = function () {
 var clubs = [{ "ClubID": 1, "CountryID": 2014, "ClubName": "CO Harrach" },
        { "ClubID": 2, "CountryID": 2018, "ClubName": "Ahly" },
        { "ClubID": 3, "CountryID": 2018, "ClubName": "Zamalek" },
        { "ClubID": 4, "CountryID": 2017, "ClubName": "Bonaberi FC" },
        { "ClubID": 5, "CountryID": 2015, "ClubName": "Benfica de Luanda" },
        { "ClubID": 6, "CountryID": 2019, "ClubName": "FC Mantes" },
        { "ClubID": 7, "CountryID": 2020, "ClubName": "Milan" },
        { "ClubID": 8, "CountryID": 2020, "ClubName": "Parma" },
        { "ClubID": 9, "CountryID": 2020, "ClubName": "Juventus" },
        { "ClubID": 10, "CountryID": 2022, "ClubName": "Liverpool" },
        { "ClubID": 11, "CountryID": 2022, "ClubName": "Mansfield" },
        { "ClubID": 12, "CountryID": 2022, "ClubName": "Arsenal" },
        { "ClubID": 13, "CountryID": 2022, "ClubName": "Manchester United" },
        { "ClubID": 14, "CountryID": 2023, "ClubName": "Real Madrid*" },
        { "ClubID": 15, "CountryID": 2023, "ClubName": "Real Sociedad" },
        { "ClubID": 16, "CountryID": 2023, "ClubName": "Barcelona" },
        { "ClubID": 17, "CountryID": 2025, "ClubName": "Santos" },
        { "ClubID": 18, "CountryID": 2025, "ClubName": "Grêmio" },
        { "ClubID": 19, "CountryID": 2025, "ClubName": "Atlético Paranaense" },
        { "ClubID": 20, "CountryID": 2025, "ClubName": "ABC Natal" }];
        
        return _.map(clubs, function (c) { return new TreeNode(c.ClubID, c.CountryID, c.ClubName);  });
};

function MyViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.countries = ko.observableArray($getCountries());
  self.clubs = ko.observableArray($getClubs());
  
  self.merge = ko.observableArray(self.countries().concat(self.clubs()));

 self.getChildren = function (parent, list) {
   return _.filter(list, function (item) { return parent.id == item.parentId; });
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'mytemplate', data: _.find(merge(), function (c) { return c.id == 0 }) }">

</ul>

<script type="text/html" id='mytemplate'>
<li>
 <span data-bind="click: () => { isOpen(!isOpen()); }, text: isOpen() ? '-' : '+'">
  </span>
  <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  <!-- ko if: isOpen-->
 <ul data-bind="template: { name: 'mytemplate', foreach: $root.getChildren($data, $root.merge()) }"></ul>
  <!-- /ko -->
</li>
</script>
```